# Problema conexion a servicio WCF en xamarin forms windows uwp

Tags: webservice, xamarin, xamarin.forms, wcf, uwp

Buenas tardes, veréis, estoy intentando conectar una solución de xamarin forms con la base de datos de sqlserver. He desarrollado un servicio wcf en visual studio, el cual realiza esta conexión. En android e ios e podido añadir ese servicio como una referencia web y la conexión se realiza de forma correcta, el problema viene en windows.

Necesito instalar este servicio en una maquina servidor, y que el resto de ordenadores cuando ejecuten la aplicación de xamarin forms en windows 10 se conectes con este a través de ese servicio. Si añado el servicio como referencia de servicio estando este instalado en mi ordenador y utilizando localhost la conexion se realiza correctamente, pero cuando en lugar de utilizar localhost utilizo la ip de la maquina me da un error de conexion con acceso denegado, incluso teniendo el firewall desactivado.

El error que me da es el de la imagen de a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que ese servicio escuchara en una maquina servidora, y que el resto de maquinas se conecten con esta  sin tener que instalar en cada una el servicio en el IIS de cada ordenador. Ojala alguien haya tenido este problema y haya podido solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola Marcos. Por favor, pon el codigo del error como texto, no como imagen. Asi es más legible, se puede copiar .. y quien use redes lentas o capadas puede leerlo sin problemas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás te faltó añadir el Capability "Internet (Client)" al manifiesto de tu app UWP?

[image: Capability Internet Client]

Comment: justamente era esto, muchísimas gracias!!